# Does something like a "group deposit" exist?

Tags: stocks, deposits

What possibilities does a private person has to merge his capital (mostly stocks) with 2-3 more different private persons?
Apart from having lesser transaction costs, which advantages or disadvantages could we have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can form an investment club with other people.

Some of the benefits include:

- Education
- Sharing ideas
- Spreading costs
- Social interaction

Drawbacks:

- Inexperienced members and poor results
- Investment clubs tend not to be regulated by the SEC but in some cases they are
- Disagreement on how to trade/invest
- Difficulty withdrawing money if you want to leave the club
- Loss of autonomy
- Theft

Answer (score 3):

In the U.S., the LLC or partnership for investing must be a non-issuer company or else it would be subject to regulation as an investment company. But personnel running the LLC or partnership, or party to it, might be subject to broker/dealer regulation or to investment advisor regulation.

Now if the non-issuer company is claiming investing as its core operation then I suppose that it is not subject to capital-gain tax but to one of two methods of corporate income tax. Also, expenses could be charged against earnings.

Comment: Then an investment club is a partnership, with investing as its core operation, that is obviously subject to capital-gain tax. So there are three different methods of taxation.

Comment: Oh, if a company with 100 or fewer beneficial owners is claiming to be a non-regulated investment company, then pass-through taxation would probably be required. Then an issuer C-corp is actually possible if with 100 or fewer shareholders and if electing pass-through taxation.

Comment: A hedge fund requires the 100 or fewer beneficial owners to be accredited investors. I suppose the difference is that the administration of the hedge fund are themselves not beneficial owners but are investment advisors.